# How can I solve my problem with tkinter in python?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, python-3.8

I got python code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import messagebox        

window = Tk()  
window.title("Шифр Цезарь")  
window.geometry('800x600')


message = StringVar()

def shifr():
    alfavit_EU =  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    alfavit_RU = 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ'
    final = ''
    action = action.get()
    message = message.get()
    step = step.get()
    lang = lang.get()
    if action == 'Шифрование':
        if lang == 'RU':
            for i in message:
                place = alfavit_RU.find(i)
                new_place = place + step
                if i in alfavit_RU:
                    final += alfavit_RU[new_place]
                else:
                     final += i
        else:
            for i in message:
                place = alfavit_EU.find(i)
                new_place = place + step
                if i in alfavit_EU:
                    final += alfavit_EU[new_place]
                else:
                    final += i  
    elif action == 'Дешифрование':
        if lang == 'RU':
            for i in message:
                 place = alfavit_RU.find(i)
                 new_place = place - step
                 if i in alfavit_RU:
                     final += alfavit_RU[new_place]
                 else:
                     final += i
        else:
            for i in message:
                place = alfavit_EU.find(i)
                new_place = place - step
                if i in alfavit_EU:
                    final += alfavit_EU[new_place]
                else:
                    final += i
    messagebox.showinfo('Результат', final)

ques_1 = Label(window, text="Что вы хотите сделать?")  
ques_1.place(x = 0, y =0)  
ques_2 = Label(window, text="Сообщение для шифровки: ")  
ques_2.place(x = 0, y =50)
ques_3 = Label(window, text="Введите шаг шифрования: ")  
ques_3.place(x = 0, y =100)
ques_4 = Label(window, text="Выберите язык RU/EU: ")  
ques_4.place(x = 0, y =150)

action = Combobox(window)
action['values'] = ('Шифрование', 'Дешифрование')
action.place(x=2, y=25)
action.current(0)

message = Entry(window,width=100, textvariable=message)
message.place(x=2, y=75)

step = Combobox(window)
step['values'] = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
step.current(0)
step.place(x=2, y=125)

lang = Combobox(window)
lang['values'] = ('RU', 'EN')
lang.current(0)
lang.place(x=2, y=175)

btn = Button(window, text="Получить результат!", command=shifr)  
btn.place(x=2, y=200)  

window.mainloop()
```

This is Caesar cipher.
When I want to get the result, it doesn't play(result is variable final).
I tried some things: write in def variables(action, etc.)with function get(), but i got problem

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'action' referenced before assignment

So, how can I solve it?

Comment: With `action = action.get()`, how do you think python is supposed to know that the `action` on the left and the `action` on the right are two different things?

Comment: So, i gotta rename action on the left side? sorry, i am new to programming, so I may have stupid questions

Comment: yes, you need to change the left side to something else.